# How to write regexp in Python which matches vowels after preceeding consonant?[b-df-hj-np-tv-xz](?=[aeiouy])

Tags: python, regex

I am stuck with regexp:

```
[b-df-hj-np-tv-xz](?=[aeiouy])
```

And the result:
**hi**e**lala**o
But I need regexp which's result would be:h**i**el**a**l**a**o

Comment: So you want vowels that are immediately preceded by non-vowels: `(?<=[^aeiouy])[aeiouy]`?

Comment: Be aware that matches vowel preceded by **any character** that is not a vowel. For example: `$a` or `%e` or `;i`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(?<=[^aeiouy])[aeiouy]`, as *jonrsharpe* proposed, is wrong, because it matches e.g.
a vowel after a **space** or a **digit**.

To do your task, use:

```
(?<=[b-df-hj-np-tv-xz])[aeiouy]
```

probably with *re.I* (ignore case) flag.

The first part (`(?<=[b-df-hj-np-tv-xz])`) is a *positive lookbehind*,
checking your condition "a vowel before".
The second part (`[aeiouy]`) matches just a single consonant.

For description of *lookarounds* (*lookbehind* and *lookahead*) search the Web.
Even on *SO* you will find plenty of explanations and examples.

For an example in *regex101* see https://regex101.com/r/Ze9hr0/1

Comment: Maybe also explain the concept of lookarounds and how these two differ.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex says "I want to match a consonant; it should be followed by a vowel". But your requirement says "I want to match a vowel; it should be preceded by a consonant".

More precisely, you want to switch from a lookahead assertion `(?=...)` to a lookbehind `(?<=...)` and probably understand the meaning of lookaround assertions. A lookaround adds a condition but does not match (or "consume") the text which meets the condition. So

```
(?<=[b-df-hj-np-tv-xz])[aeiouy]
```

matches a vowel, but only on the condition that the immediately preceding character satisfies the lookbehind.

Comment: Maybe include `y` in the consonants, too, if your target language is English or another language where a `y` before a vowel becomes a consonant.